# HTML slideshow or carousel style from apple watch

Tags: slideshow, carousel

Hi I see apple's website has this really fancy slideshow (or carousel) like below:

```
http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch
```

I am hoping to implement a similar slideshow. The demo from jssor is the closest that I found:

```
http://www.jssor.com/demos/carousel-slider.slider
```

Does anyone know how I can implement something like the apple-watch website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is easy to use:
[slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Nice answer