# HTML carousel/slide show on apples website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, slick.js

I found this carousel on [apples website](http://www.apple.com/uk/music/radio/) where it has the 3 radio presenters, and was wondering how i could create this effect or if there is a carousel like this available.

I did some research and found a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197196/html-slideshow-or-carousel-style-from-apple-watch) which links to slick.js so I am wondering if apple use slick and have customized it to do this or they found a new carousel that makes this effect occur.

From inspecting the carousel i found the class `zine-gallery-content` but searching that didn't help.

Does anyone know how i can make this carousel? It is also responsive.

Comment: Looking at just the .zine-* classes there are quite a few things going on on that website. In http://images.apple.com/v/music/b/scripts/main.built.js you will find the code that triggers the gallery sliders, but you'll probably won't find that useful. It's not really clear if they use an existing package, it looks pretty much like custom-made code to me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks custom to me. They've called it 'ac-gallery' within their code. They tend to prepend things with `ac-`, `ac-analytics`, etc.

I'll let you know how I figured this out. I inspected the slider and was looking for a wrapper class or ID with the words 'gallery', 'carousel', 'slider' or something similar. I noticed the carousel contained the ID `#zine-gallery`. I then looked for one of their javascript files that looked like the primary file where most of the code is compiled to. I found a file called `main.built.js`. I opened this file and searched for `zine-gallery`, which did exist. I then opened my web inspector, opened the "Sources" tab and found main.built.js. I then clicked the "Pretty Print" button (The `{}` icon next to the line and column number. This formats the uglified javascript and allows you to read it more easily.

The following leads me to believe it's custom:

```
this.gallery = B.create({
    id: this.galleryId,
    el: this.wrapper,
    section: this,
    model: this.slides,
    triggerSelector: this.triggerSelector,
    trigger: {
        events: ["mouseover", "click"]
    }
})
```

Usually a plugin would include it's name in the creation process. Also, right below the following gallery methods are defined:

`C._removeActiveStates`,
`C._animateNewStation`,
`C._blendToNewBackgroundColor`,
`C.activate`,
`C.deactivate`,
`C.animateIn`,
`C.onRequestAnimationFrame`,
`C.onScroll`,
`C.onResize`, etc.

Comment: do you think it is possible to recreate this with something like slick.js or bootstrap carousel?

I found this link which shows how to customize bootstrap carousel http://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-carousel-with-css3-animations/

Comment: I had a look at slick.js and they do support callbacks (or events in their case) like most carousels do, so you would be able to mimic apple's animations, but it would all be custom work aside from the carousel part.